# Is there a term for expressions usually rendered as names but are meant to be humorous?

Tags: names, humor

The expressions about which I am asking are used often on "Prairie Home Companion" when the narrator delivers a list of "fake" credits at the end of the show or at the end of a comic bit.

For example, I.P. Freely, Iona Ford, Ilene Down, Max A Million, etc.  Is there a technical term for this type of expression.  I guess these could be a type of pun.

Comment: There's also Winnie the Pooh. You wouldn't believe his credentials

Comment: Have you ever read *Cliff Tragedy* by Eileen Dover?

Comment: I was asked one time if Winnie the Pooh used shampoo.  I replied, "No, Winnie uses real pooh!"

Comment: I wouldn't call these "expressions" at all, they're just humorous made-up names. The nearest technical term I can come up with is [nominative determinism](http://www.science-frontiers.com/sf108/sf108p14.htm), coined by New Scientist many years ago, which is for *real names* reflecting people's actual jobs. I think they still print a few more in their "Feedback" penultimate page every now and then.

Comment: Wait til Biggus Dickus hears of this!  He has a wife, you know.  Do you know what she's called?  She's called Incontinentia.  Incontinentia Buttocks.

Comment: Nevermind Prairie Home Companion. Check out the [Car Talk Credits](http://www.cartalk.com/content/about/credits/credits.html).

Comment: Thanks to the long-running BBC radio series "I'm Sorry I Haven't a Clue" these are known as "Late Arrivals".

Answer (score 5):

These are indeed puns. You could also call them [double entendres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre), [pun names](http://wiki.name.com/en/Pun_Names) or [gag names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gag_name).

Comment: I propose "jocunym".