# What is the technique that produces phrases like "Miss Anne Thrope" called and is there a master list of names?

Tags: idioms, differences, synonyms, terminology

Misanthrope, as a word, can be converted into the pseudonym "Miss Anne Thrope" (bonus points if the meaning reflects the writer's style).

But what is this technique called and is there a master list of names?

Comment: The suggestion that there could be a "master list" of such names does imply that someone is responsible for maintaining/enforcing such a list. There might be lists and they might or might not be consistent with each other but there probably isn't a "master list".

Comment: I'd call it a **pun**, it would be difficult to pull it off verbally but set to page it would work

Comment: For myself it's a quest to find more

Comment: There's the specific term [***nominative determinism***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism#:~:text=easily%20verifiable%20sources.-,Definition,possibly%20subconsciously%2C%20made%20themselves%20fit.) for "real" cases, such as a clarinet-playing musician called Clara Knet, or a surgeon called Dr Butcher. But made-up examples don't have a special name - they're just wordplay / puns. And the idea of there being a "master list" is just ridiculous. There's not even a single "master list" of all and only valid English *words*, let alone puns!

Comment: Related, maybe: [“books never written”](https://www.boyscouttrail.com/content/joke/books_never_written-850.asp)

Comment: Beanoisms? I found [this list](https://upjoke.com/eileen-dover-jokes) by searching for "Eileen Dover" + "jokes".

Comment: Mel N. Colley, Manda Wren, Rose Bowle…Rolle Tide! Uh, bye. Good luck.

Comment: Retirement Planning by Ilga N. Gains. https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/entertainthis/2014/11/03/car-talk-tom-magliozzi-credits/77368658/

Comment: And the infamous law firm of Dewey, Cheatum & Howe. Come to think of it, "Frida Kahlo" could be understood as a plea to liberate those lacking in adult sophistication.

Comment: There's a genre of jokes with books by apposite people, like Broken Windows by Eva Brick. But there doesn't seem to be a standard name, these seem to be just called things like "funny books", "joke/punny authors", "author puns", "joke names", etc. Another class is the sort of fake name Bart Simpson uses in prank phonecalls. And then there are many more.

Comment: Isn't this the basis of many drag names? Hedda Lettuce, Summer Klerance, Lanja Ray

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Is there a term for expressions usually rendered as names but are meant to be humorous?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41042/is-there-a-term-for-expressions-usually-rendered-as-names-but-are-meant-to-be-hu), but my VTC has been used up here.

Answer (score 1):

Those phrases should be termed "homophone phrases" in AmE. This nomenclature is used for phrases that result from reduction, but the principe being the same as far as what is considered are multi-word combinations of different spelling and sense having the same pronunciation, combinations such as "Misanthrope/Miss Anne Thrope" should be identified by the same word. (Note: "an" is usually reduced in "misanthrope" (n), rarely pronounced "ann".)

[Rachel's English](https://rachelsenglish.com/homophone-phrases/): homophone phrases brought about by reduction (had her/hatter, got a/got to); there is  on this site an extensive list of such phrases.

Comment: I asked ChatGPT and it likened my query to "aptronym" or "aptonym" (the practice of creating names that play on the sounds or meanings of words), although your explanation also hits the mark. Suggestions were: "Les Ismore", "Paige Turner" and "Anita Bath" (I need a bath).

Comment: important in English is not the same as French, where it means a major x.

Comment: @Lambie It took your remark for me to realize that; I still  checked the dictionaries, albeit without much hope, and you are right. Thanks!